# Pyramid/SQLAlchemy displaying objects

Tags: python, object, sqlalchemy, pyramid, object-oriented-database

I'm creating a record system, where a student can be enrolled into a class.

```
# MODEL
class Association(Base):
__tablename__ = 'association'
class_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('classes.id'), primary_key=True)
student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('students.id'), primary_key=True)
theClass = relationship("Class")

class Student(Base):
__tablename__ = 'students'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(30))
classlist = relationship("Association", backref='student')

class Class(Base):
__tablename__ = 'classes'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
teacher_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teachers.id'))
enrolled_students = relationship("Association")
```

I want to display all of the students that are not yet enrolled in a class, so I've used the following code in my program and template, but it just displays all of the students on the page.

```
currentClass = session.query(Class).filter_by(id=class_id).first()
students = session.query(Student).all()

# TEMPLATE
% for st in students:
% for assoc in currentClass.enrolled_students:
% if st.id != assoc.student_id:
    <input type="checkbox" name="student_id" value="${ st.id }" >${ st.id } - ${ st.forename } ${ st.surname }</input><br/> 
% endif
% endfor
% endfor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code even outputs each student name as many times as there are students in the current class (minus one if the student is enrolled in the class) :)

Your current logic is

```
for student in all_student:  # Alice, Bob, Claude
    for enrolled_student in current_class.enrolled_students: # Alice, Bob
        if student != enrolled_student:
            print student
```

The output of the above would be

```
Alice, Alice, Bob, Bob, Claude, Claude, Claude
```

(first iteration: Alice == Alice, skip. Second: Alice != Bob, print. Third: Alice != Claude, print, etc.)

Also your relationship setup is not quite "idiomatic sqlalchemy". Have a look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many If you set up your models as in the example (e.q. using the `secondary` parameter of the `relationship()` function), you'll be able to do something like

```
% for st in students:
% if st not in class.enrolled_students:
    <input type="checkbox" name="student_id" value="${ st.id }" >${ st.id } - ${ st.forename } ${ st.surname }</input><br/> 
% endif
% endfor
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think the problem (as you mentioned) was with the relationship setup. Thank you!

Comment: Kudos for answering such a mess

Comment: @amarz121: actually, the problem is with the general algorithm of checking "if the student is not enrolled in the class", it will work incorrectly even with plain Python lists. It is coincidental that the change in relationship configuration fixes that.

Comment: @Sergey: I had tried the algorithm you suggested before, but I got errors, I didn't think there was an issue with the model, but after modifying the model it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is all wrong..

```
students = Session.query(Student).\
            filter(Student.classlist == None).all()

for student ins students:
     <input type="checkbox" name="student_id" value="${ st.id }" >${ st.id } - ${ st.forename } ${ st.surname }</input><br/>
endfor
```

Comment: I don't think you can filter by the `classlist` attribute - it's a relationship defined on the Python side, there's no such field in the database.

Comment: @crooksey - That's not what I intended to do either. I wanted to display students that are not already enrolled in the particular class, not students that are not enrolled on any class at all, but thanks for helping.